# Getting user inputs to be used in an array

Tags: c#, arrays, methods, input

In this code I am attempting to write requires that I make a small menu, and for A to take 5 integers, and B to display them, C and D are // out because I don't have to code those sections yet, but for some reason I can't get the integers to input right, and for them to be displayed with B. My main question is how can I get 5 user inputs inside of  loadarray and then use that array in displayarray?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    char choice;
    int[] Num = new interger[5];

    do
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Choice = Menu();

        switch (choice)
        {
            case 'A':
            case 'a':
                lArray(Num);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 'B':
            case 'b':
                dArray(Num);
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 'C':
            case 'c':
            //    Console.WriteLine("Sum: {0}", cSum(Num));
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 'D':
            case 'd':
            //    Console.WriteLine("Average: {0}", cAverage(Num));
                Console.ReadLine();
                break;
            case 'Z':
            case 'z':
                break;
            default:
                Console.WriteLine("Invalid number!");
                break;
        }
    } 
    while (choice != 'Z' && choice != 'z');
}

static char Menu()
{
    char Input;
    string[] strOptions = new string[] {
        "A. Add num",
        "B. Display num",
        "C. Output sum ",
        "D. Output average",
        "z. Exit"
    };

    Console.WriteLine("What would you like to do?");
    foreach(string strValue in strOptions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(strValue);
    }

    do
    {
        Console.Write("Please select from A to Z: ");
        Input = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
    while ((Input < 'A' || Input > 'Z') && (Input < 'a' || Input > 'z'));
    return Input;
}

static int lArray(int[] array)
{
    int[] newArray = new int[5];

    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.Length; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    }

}

static int dArray(int[] array)
{
    return loadArray;
}






        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Declare in your class (which contains these method) static field `private static int[] newArray;`.  And use this field instead of local variable in `loadArray` method and in `displayArray` method.

Comment: I'm sorry I don't really understand, I made the adjustments but now it still won't work.

Comment: Read [10.4.1 Static and instance fields](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645751(v=vs.71).aspx) and find some C# basics tutorial

Comment: Please do not vandalize your own post by removing your code.  If you want to remove your question, delete it.